# Can I Change Variable with KeyListener?

Tags: java, keylistener

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int setNum = 1;
                if(e.getKeyCode() == 'u'|| e.getKeyCode() == 'U' && setNum == 1) {
                    setNum = 2;
                }
```

This is part of 2Player Tetris game code :: key setting

```
                if(e.getKeyCode() == 'u'|| e.getKeyCode() == 'U' && setNum == 2) {
                    setNum = 1;
                }
                if(setNum == 1) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'a' || e.getKeyCode() == 'A') {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece, board1.curX - 1, board1.curY);
                    }   
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'd' || e.getKeyCode() == 'D') {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece, board1.curX + 1, board1.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 's' || e.getKeyCode() == 'S') {
                        board1.oneLineDown();
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'w' || e.getKeyCode() == 'W') {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece.rotateLeft(), board1.curX, board1.curY);
                    }   
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                        board1.dropDown();
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece, board2.curX + 1, board2.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece, board2.curX - 1, board2.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        board2.oneLineDown();               
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece.rotateLeft(), board2.curX, board2.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        board2.dropDown();  
                    }

                }
```

When setNum = 1; Player 1 can play with WASD, and Player 2 can play with arrow Key

```
                else if(setNum == 2) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == '2' || e.getKeyCode() == '2') {
                        setNum = 1; 
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'a' || e.getKeyCode() == 'A') {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece, board2.curX - 1, board2.curY);
                    }   
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'd' || e.getKeyCode() == 'D') {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece, board2.curX + 1, board2.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 's' || e.getKeyCode() == 'S') {
                        board2.oneLineDown();
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == 'w' || e.getKeyCode() == 'W') {
                        board2.tryMove(board2.curPiece.rotateLeft(), board2.curX, board2.curY);
                    }   
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                        board2.dropDown();
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece, board1.curX + 1, board1.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece, board1.curX - 1, board1.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        board1.oneLineDown();               
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                        board1.tryMove(board1.curPiece.rotateLeft(), board1.curX, board1.curY);
                    }
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        board1.dropDown();  
                    }

                }
```

And setNum =2; Player1 can play with Arrow key, and Player2 can play with wasd Key.

- I want to make code that When pressed 'U' key, change key setting with player1 and player2. 
  (WASD SHIFT <-> Arrow key and SPACEBAR)

But my code dosen't work. How can I do?

Comment: `setNum` is local to the `keyPressed()` method. Were you wanting to change something outside the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The useful answer is that should probably do the key processing before leaving the event listener. That is, call the relevant method with appropriate arguments from the anonymous inner class.

The literal minimal answer would be to move the declaration of `setNum` out to the appropriate scope. If the appropriate scope is not a class (i.e. it wont be a field), then you have the additional problem of it having to be effectively final but there's plenty of other questions dealing with that.